# 64-bit DBeaver can't connect to ODBC source - “Unexpected driver error occurred while connecting to database”

Tags: odbc, database-connection, dbeaver

I want to make new connection ODBC in Dbeaver. The test result in ODBC driver is `'successfully connected to data source'`. So in Dbeaver i just click new connection database then ODBC, i fill the Database/Schema in Dbeaver same with Data Source in ODBC, also i fill username and password like in ODBC and i didn't change any settings. But i get the following error like this:

```
'Unexpected driver error occurred while connecting to database'
```

should i change any settings in Dbeaver?

Comment: To what type of database are you trying to connect? Does it not have a JDBC driver? DBeaver's ODBC connectivity feature uses the old and deprecated JDBC-ODBC Bridge components from Java 7, and they have a reputation for being a bit dodgy.

Comment: Anyway the problem has been solved ya. I try to fill Database/schema in Dbeaver same with Data Source Name in ODBC but getting error: '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified'. So i try to add the data in System DSN not in User DSN. Then i can connect ODBC to Dbeaver. Thank you for your comment :)